# SQL: Return with simple SQL statement

Tags: sql

```
student_id   course_id   course_name
---------------------------------------------
1            1000        'CS'
2            1000        'CS'
1            2000        'CHEM'
2            3000        'ENG'
3            1000        'CS'
4            5000        'Bio'
```

I'm trying to return (student_id, course_id, course_name) that take one course,
using a simple SQL statement, without Subquery and JOIN.

Result should be:

```
Student_ID Course_ID Course_name
3          1000      'CS'
4          5000      'Bio'
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: You should have to post SQL statement.

Answer (score 3):

try this, as per your requirement, without subquery or join

```
select student_id, min(course_id), min(course_name) from student
group by student_id
having count(student_id) = 1
```

this will return the student details who take only one course

Comment: If min() wad needed, there was more then 1 hit per selected fields?

Comment: @Jonas: Not necessarily, you *must* use aggregate functions in SQL for columns or expressions that are not dependent on the columns that are part of the `group by` clause.